# ¿Qué significa que tempdb no se modifique?

Tags: sql-server

Lo primero considerad que tengo pocos conocimientos en sql server.

Tengo unos jobs que se ejecutan diariamente en sql server. 
Hemos ido controlando el tamaño  de la base de datos ya que ha ido creciendo diariamente. Esto es normal ya que se van generando datos diariamente hasta que lleguen al tiempo límite que hemos establecido, tiene que llegar un momento en el que se estabilice.

Mi pregunta viene porque los procesos almacenados se están ejecutando correctamente todos los días y no dan error pero el tamaño de la base de datos ha dejado de crecer desde hace unos días cuando aún debería seguir creciendo.

He visto que los archivos tempdb no se han modificado desde el día 30/09 que es la misma fecha en la que dejó de crecer la base de datos. ¿Esto por qué puede ser? ¿Qué significa que los archivos tempdb no se modifiquen? ¿Qué es lo que está fallando y no soy capaz de ver?

Muchas gracias de antemano y lo siento si me he extendido en exceso, he intentado ser lo más claro posible.

Answer (score 2):

**Tempdb** es una base de datos del sistema SQL Server que almacena básicamente objetos temporales (tablas e índices temporales locales o globales, procedimientos almacenados temporales..) u objetos internos que se crean mediante el motor de base de datos (consultas GROUP BY, ORDER BY o UNION...)

La base de datos **tempdb** se vuelve a crear cada vez que se inicia SQL Server, de forma que el sistema siempre se inicia con una copia limpia de la base de datos. Las tablas y los procedimientos almacenados temporales se quitan automáticamente en la desconexión y ninguna conexión permanece activa cuando se cierra el sistema. Por tanto, en la base de datos tempdb no hay nada que deba guardarse de una a otra sesión de SQL Server. No se permite realizar operaciones de copia de seguridad y restauración en tempdb.

Lo más seguro es que en las primeras ejecuciones se haya tenido que autoincrementar el tamaño de los ficheros y posteriormente, como no se ha llegado al nuevo máximo valor, no se han vuelto a modificar. Pero no debería alarmarte mucho que no crezca esta base de datos, es más, que se esté autoincrementando a menudo puede afectar en el rendimiento.

Te dejo una documentación de microsoft sobre la base de datos tempdb: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Es importante señalar, que la base de datos tempdb se crea con el tamaño predefinido cada vez que se reinicia la instancia. Por lo tanto, es recomendado aumentar ese tamaño a algo que no requiera crecer en un futuro cercano (excepto por situaciones extraordinarias como cargar un gran volumen de datos).